# Finding and replacing in a list using user input (python)

Tags: python, list

I need help with an extra credit portion of my assignment. The objective is to make a list and then allow the user to input their own data (in this case birds) and then it sort and return the birds. The extra credit portion is to allow the user to edit any info after. I don't know how to find/replace what a user gives it.

code:

```
def sorted_list():
    bird_list.sort()
    for i in bird_list:
        print(i)
    print()
    print('There are', len(bird_list), 'birds in the list.')
    #end for
#end def

cond = 'y'

while cond == 'y':
    bird = input('Type the name of another bird (RETURN when finished): ')
    if bird in bird_list:
        print(bird, 'is already in the list.')
    else:
        bird_list.append(bird)
        print(bird, 'has been added to the list.')
    if bird == '':
        cond = 'n'
        sorted_list()
    #end if
#end while

edit = input('Edit? (y/n) ')

print()
if edit == 'y':
    change = input('Which bird would you like to change? ')
    if change == bird_list[0]:
        i = input('Enter correction ' )
    else:
        print('Entry not found in list')
```

EDIT:

resolved the edit issue using this

```
if edit == 'y':
    change = input('Which bird would you like to change? ')
    if change in bird_list:
        loc = bird_list.index(change)
        bird_list.remove(change)
        correction = input('Enter correction ' )
        bird_list.insert(loc, correction)
    else:
        print('Entry not found in list')
```

Comment: Well my attempt at it was everything underneath where it says edit. But what happens is, say I enter crow which would be place 0 on the list, i get 'Entry not found on list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use `.index` to find an item's position in a list.

But there is another problem in your code, which is the reason you got the `'Entry not found on list'` output when you enter a name which would be at index 0 in the list, that is the **first time** you enter a blank string(enter the `Enter` key without input nothing), you append a blank string bird name in you `bird_list`, and your `sorted_list` method sort the blank string `''` in the first place of the list, here:

```
if bird in bird_list:
    print(bird, 'is already in the list.')
# if bird is ''(first time), it will be appended to the list, too
else:
    bird_list.append(bird)
    print(bird, 'has been added to the list.')
if bird == '':
    cond = 'n'
    # and this will sort '' in the 0 index of the list
    sorted_list()
```

the correct logic should be:

```
if bird in bird_list:
    print(bird, 'is already in the list.')
elif bird != '':
    bird_list.append(bird)
    print(bird, 'has been added to the list.')
else:
    cond = 'n'
    sorted_list()
```

Comment: Thank you very much @LarryLee! we haven't learned about elif statements yet or != which made the code look a lot nicer. i also wasn't getting "  has been added to the list." when i pressed return to finish. This was a great help.

The thing I'm still having trouble with is having it use index to find the user generated input. So i was able to use index when i was just looking for list[0] but now i want it to be anything they put. Everything I've tried so far just gives me the return "Entry not found in list"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you intend to find the position of an arbitrary bird given their name. To find an item with a specific value in a python list, use `list.index`. [stdtypes documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq)